# Jsoup and specific element under TD

Tags: java, android, href, jsoup, html-table

I'm developing an app based on Jsoup Parsing. I love this class because it's so useful, but just now I have a problem. 
I can't unterstand how to select a specific element of an html page that now I'll represent by an example.

```
<table>
<tr>

<td class=default1>
   <a href "pickthisurl.com"> text </a>
   <a><href="uselesslink.com">text </a>
</td>
<td class=default1>
   <a href "pickthisurl.com">text </a>
   <a><href="uselesslink.com">text </a>
</td>
<td class=default1>
   <a href "pickthisurl.com">text</a>
   <a><href="uselesslink.com">text</a>
</td>

<tr>
</table>
```

So, what I need is the url of the first  under each td with that class.
I'm trying with something like

Elements links = doc.select("td.default1 > a[href]");

but this code select (and It's right) all links elements!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Elements td = doc.select("td.default1");
for(Element el : td)
{
   el.select("a[href]").first();
}
```

Comment: thanks so much it works with a little add
Elements td = doc.select("td.default1");
for(Element el : td)
{
  string element1= el.select("a[href]").first();
  string elementjusturl=element1.urlvariazione.attr("abs:href");
}